# object->delete() on related object does not immediately persist

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have a one (procedure) to many (tools) relationship set up.  Sometimes I want to delete all the tools associated with a procedure:

```
class Procedure extends BaseProcedure
{
  ...

  function deleteTools()
  {
    $aProcedure = $this;
    $someCondition = true;

    foreach( $aProcedure->getTools() as $tool )
    {
      if($someCondition) {
        $tool->delete();
      }
    }

    $aProcedure->save();  // Right Here!
  }
}

class ProcedureActions extends sfActions
{
  ...

  public function executeTest(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->procedure = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
    $this->procedure->deleteTools();
    $this->action = "show";
    $this->setTemplate("show", "procedure");
  }

}
```

At this line, I get the following error message:

> "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'procedure_id' cannot be null".  Digging around I see that this sql statement is being prepared.
>
> execute : INSERT INTO procedure_tools (id, procedure_id, tool_id,
>   status_id, itemcount, comment) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) - (, , , , ,
>   )

It appears to me that the related procedure is not aware of the delete yet.  I can't figure out how to get around this though.  The delete *is* working.  A second refresh and everything is correct.  Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

**(1)** Edited to clarify an more accurately represent my scenario. Apologies for not doing so in the first place.

**(2)** Edited to show the context around the whole function.  There will be more logic in there (specifically to evaluate $someCondition, but currently this always evaluates to true).  Also the content of the initiating action is show, in case I'm conjuring the object in the wrong way.

**(3)** Edited to add, code from the showSuccess template.

```
<?php foreach($procedure->getTools() as $tool): ?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $tool->getId() ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $tool->getStatus() ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $tool->getName() ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you perform all delete after ? This way, you only perform one query to delete many tools.

```
$toolsToDelete = array();
foreach( $aProcedure->getTools() as $tool )
{
  if($someCondition) {
    $toolToDelete[] = $tool->getId();
  }
}

$aProcedure->save();  // Right Here!

Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->delete('Tools t')
  ->whereIn('t.id', $toolsToDelete)
  ->execute();
```

**edit:**

What happend in your template, is that Doctrine already fetch the relation `Tools`, so it's somehow *cached*. That's why in your template, you still have deleted tool and don't have them on page reload.

I can't remember how I managed to do this in the past, but you can try to [`refresh`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Record.php#L956) the object and its relations. So instead of :

```
$aProcedure->save();  // Right Here!
```

Try:

```
$aProcedure->refresh(true);
```

ps: I assume that you perform nothing else on `$aProcedure` in your `deleteTools()` function. Otherwise, you shouldn't remove the `save()`.

Comment: This is a good idea, thanks.  I was really focused on figuring why I was getting the error, I didn't consider alternatives.  I've just implemented this suggestion and it introduces a new problem.  After deleting the items, the action redirects to a "show" view.  The view isn't being updated with the deletes.  If I refresh then I see them, but initially the view isn't getting the message.  Maybe I need to save the tools table...?

Comment: Update your question with what you do before the `foreach` (mostly related to `$aProcedure`) and what do you display in your `show` view.

Comment: thanks so much!  This is exactly it.  I had tried using refresh() in the distant past, but didn't read closely enough about the deep setting, so it never refreshed the related items.  Thanks again, you've been so much help!

Answer (score 1):

The `foreach` loop is not necessary, and likely the cause of your troubles.

```
$aProcedure->Tools->delete();
```

Done.

Comment: Unfortunately I realize I oversimplified. I'm not actually wanting to delete all of them - I could use delete from the doctrine_collection as you suggest.  I actually want to delete certain items based on a criteria.